# No module named kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have installed kivy, and kivy is in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, but when i `import kivy` in python shell i get:

```
>>> import kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named kivy
```

When i run `sudo apt-get install python-kivy` again:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-kivy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What is happening? I have Debian 8.5. It can't be found using `whereis, which`:

```
amir@amir-debian:~$ whereis kivy
kivy:
amir@amir-debian:~$ which python-kivy
amir@amir-debian:~$ whereis python-kivy
python-kivy:
```

It is also not shown under loaded modules:

```
import sys

print "*" * 30
for k in sys.modules:
        print "->", k
print "*" * 30

>>> ******************************
-> copy_reg
-> sre_compile
-> _sre
-> encodings
-> site
-> __builtin__
-> sysconfig
-> __main__
-> encodings.encodings
-> abc
-> posixpath
-> _weakrefset
-> errno
-> encodings.codecs
-> sre_constants
-> re
-> _abcoll
-> types
-> _codecs
-> _warnings
-> genericpath
-> stat
-> zipimport
-> encodings.__builtin__
-> warnings
-> UserDict
-> encodings.utf_8
-> sys
-> codecs
-> os.path
-> signal
-> traceback
-> linecache
-> posix
-> encodings.aliases
-> exceptions
-> sre_parse
-> os
-> _weakref
******************************
```

Comment: Is your python shell the same python2.7 in which Kivy is installed? What is in `sys.path`?

Comment: yes, my python is 2.7.3 and i have installed python-kivy (and not python3-kivy). `sys.path` is `['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/amir/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`.

Comment: try installing kivy using it's documentation it it's official site.

Comment: Well, looks like the pythonpath doesn't include the dist-packages folder where kivy is, so that would explain why it isn't imported. This seems like an ubuntu related problem, but I don't know why it's come about.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a REALLY long time. I fixed it by changing the Python path I was using to build and run the code. The path had to include the directories with all the kivy files.